# Java Swing show icon button and JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a simple program to learn about Java Swing. I want an Icon button and a label to show the latest ActionEvent. However, with this code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MyProgram implements ActionListener {
    JButton b1;
    JFrame f;
    JLabel ael;
    int i = 1;
    MyProgram() throws Exception {
        f = new JFrame();
        URL img = new URL("https://c.tenor.com/cSNnlTEM4rUAAAAM/booze-man.gif");
        ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
        b1 = new JButton("Click me or you'll be punched!", imgIcon);
        b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        b1.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.TOP);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setActionCommand("Button click");
        f.getContentPane().add(b1);
        ael = new JLabel("Latest action event: NULL");
        f.add(ael);
        f.pack();
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MyProgram();
                }catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        });
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
        b1.setText("Thanks!");
        ael.setText("Latest action event: " + ae.getActionCommand());
        try {
        b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Emoji_u1f44d.svg/120px-Emoji_u1f44d.svg.png")));
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        b1.setActionCommand("Button click after activation number: " + i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

It only shows the `ael` label.
I have tried packing the frame twice, but then it will only show the `b1` button.
Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please tell us the details of your code and your problem.  Your question is missing information.

Comment: This, `f.setLayout(null);` is very very bad. Get rid of it and learn to use the layout managers. That is your problem, you're ignoring the placement and positioning of components and compounding it with null l ayouts.

Comment: Thanks, using BoxLayout seems to fix the problem!